# Why does SELECT not read committed rows while more are being written?

Tags: sql-server

My understanding of locks in SQL Server is that when an operator is writing, it acquires an X lock only on the rows it is writing to for the duration of the transaction. So if I try to select from a table that is being written to, it should return all previously committed rows (under the default transaction level `READ COMMITTED`).

Based on this, I have created a stored procedure to check.

```
USE [SANDPIT]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[slowly_insert_into_adventure_time_characters]

AS
  SET XACT_ABORT OFF  -- Turn off auto abort on errors
  SET NOCOUNT ON      -- Turn off row count messages

BEGIN TRANSACTION;    
  INSERT INTO SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters([name])
    VALUES
      ('Jake')
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  INSERT INTO SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters([name])
    VALUES
      ('Finn')
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  INSERT INTO SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters([name])
    VALUES
      ('Princess Bubblegum')
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  INSERT INTO SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters([name])
    VALUES
      ('Abracadaniel')
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  INSERT INTO SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters([name])
    VALUES
      ('Earl of Lemongrab')
COMMIT;
GO
```

If I run the stored procedure and then `SELECT * FROM SANDPIT.dbo.adventure_time_characters` while it is running, the query appears to wait until the stored procedure finishes then returns the new values. This is weird to me because I expected the select statement to return an empty table because at the time it was run there were no committed rows in the table.

Similarly, if I run the stored procedure again and select while it is running, I expect to see the previously commit rows, but not the new ones. However again it waits before returning everything.

My hypothesis is that because I have no where condition on my select statement, it is trying to select everything including rows that have an X lock and that is why it waits. I modified everything to include a where clause that only returns previously committed rows but I got the same results. I assumed this because it has to check every row to know which rows satisfy the where condition. So, I tried to add an nonclustered index but the same thing happened.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running the second query on the same connection?

Comment: The legacy default behavior with SQL Server `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level is pessimistic locking instead of optimistic row versioning. If you turn on the database `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option (the default with Azure SQL Databse), you see the behavior you expect (empty until the transaction commits).

Comment: If you select while inserting, your select might run into a "non-committed" row and then it will wait until it gets committed. If you don't want that, use a  `WITH (READPAST)` query hint to skip non-committed rows when selecting.

Comment: So my read query does block because I am trying to select a row with an X lock on it. So why does SQL Server not lock the whole table instead of locking the row? When would I be able to select from a table (using `READ_COMMITTED` without `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`) while it is simultaneously being written to? I assume this is the scenario that row locks are trying to enable. @marc_s

Comment: @Blindy, yes I think so.

Comment: "When would I be able to select from a table (using READ_COMMITTED without READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT) while it is simultaneously being written to?" - when the SELECT query doesn't have to encounter a non committed row. e.g. if you have a `WHERE` clause where matching row(s) can be found by an index without having to scan past uncommitted rows

Comment: Locking the whole table is overkill - after all, if you have a *focused* `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause, chances are quite high you won't encounter any newly inserted rows. And as I already said - if you use the `WITH (READPAST)` query hint, your `SELECT` will just skip over any locked rows it might encounter and return everything else just fine - no blocking, no waiting